# How to store IList (Collection) of C# as Json document in DynamoDb

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a `ASP.Net Core 2.1` app which is using `DynamoDb` as Db (NoSql)

DTO

```
public class CustomerTO
{  
 public string Id{get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public IList<Contact> Contacts {get; set;}
}


public class Contact
{
 public string Number {get; set;}
 public string Address { get; set;}
}
```

I am using Low Level API for `DynamoDb` CRUD. This is how my method looks like

```
public async Task<CustomerTO> Add(CustomerTO obj)
    {
        try
        {

            var res = await _dynamoClient.PutItemAsync(tableName: _tableName, item: SetObject(obj));
            if (res.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return obj;
            }
            else
            {
                //throw new Exception("Error" + res);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Logger.Log(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> SetObject(CustomerTO obj)
    {


        //DynamoDb - Using Low Level API
        var attributes = new Dictionary<string,
        AttributeValue> {
            //Id
            {
                nameof(obj.Id),
                new AttributeValue {
                    S = obj.Id
                }
            },

            //Name
            {
                nameof(obj.Name),
                new AttributeValue {
                    S = obj.Name
                }
            },
            {
                nameof(obj.Contacts),
                new AttributeValue
                {
                   S = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj.Contacts)
                }
            }
        };

        //attributes[nameof(obj.Contacts)] = Document.FromJson(obj.Contacts);
        return attributes;
    }
```

This is storing the Contacts fields as a string with escape characters as

```
[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Number\": \"a6e8003e-3991-4f0c-a47f-49b26d6d83c0\",\r\n    \"Address\": \"Free\"}]
```

As I am passing as a string so quite obvious it would store as string.

But how do I convert this Contacts as fields so that it is stored as an `Array`, `List (L)` or `JSON` string with no escape characters?

Thanks!

Comment: @Fildor, newlines & excess spaces.

Comment: Have you considered making the Contacts their own Document and saving the respective ids in customer?

Comment: @Fildor, yes, You mean the contact as its different item

Comment: Yes. But I am not sure if that's a good idea in Dynamo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Newtonsoft to convert it into the data type you want. Consider change from dynamic type to list or array

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
```

Or use

JavaScriptSerializer under System.Web.Script.Serialization Or

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);
```

Json.Decode under System.Web.Helpers

```
dynamic jsonObject = Json.Decode(json);
```